Can Blazor WASM make SOAP calls?
I'm attempting to call an Onvif web service (actually a whole bunch) via SOAP from blazor wasm. I have generated the necessary files from the service's wsdl although it seems that the current implementation in .net 8 doesn't support this quite yet. I'm looking for any reasonable workaround before I give up. I was thinking other SOAP libraries might be worth looking at (ServiceStack?) but I wanted to check if anyone has run into anything similar as of yet.
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
   at System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpHandler.set_AutomaticDecompression(DecompressionMethods value)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.set_AutomaticDecompression(DecompressionMethods value)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.<GetHttpClientAsync>d__51[[System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel, System.ServiceModel.Primitives, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].MoveNext()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpClientRequestChannel.<GetHttpClientAsync>d__27[[System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel, System.ServiceModel.Primitives, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].MoveNext()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpClientRequestChannel.HttpClientChannelAsyncRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__13[[System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel, System.ServiceModel.Primitives, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].MoveNext()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.RequestAsync(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.RequestAsyncInternal(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[SendAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<CreateGenericTask>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at QuickNV.Onvif.OnvifClient.ConnectAsync() in C:\Code\QuickNV.Onvif\src\QuickNV.Onvif\OnvifClient.cs:line 85
   at CameraWasmApp.Pages.Login.Connect(LoginArgs loginArgs) in C:\Code\CameraWasmApp\CameraWasmApp\Pages\Login.razor.cs:line 28


Yes you can make a call to a SOAP service from Blazor WASM, but what you are seeing is the Onvif Client attempting to use features that are not available in the browser - you should probably look for a different client, generate a new client SDK from their WSDL or create the SOAP calls yourself.

Perhaps make the call server-side?
